# ASP.NET scriptmanager getting error 500 when posting to server with AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager

I asked a question yesterday where it was closed with duplication reason,
However I still did not get an answer how to resolve my issue and i need some assistance.

I am using ASP.NET with script manager

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />
```

I am getting error 500 when trying to post data to server.

**Bad code with Error 500:**

CS:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetCurrentBaseVersion(string id)
{
    // need to get here
}
```

JS:

```
function postNewBaseLine() {
    var id = "300";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ManagerBaseKit.aspx/SetCurrentBaseVersion",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'id' :id},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success!');
        },
        statusCode: {
            500: function () {
                alert('got error 500');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What I found so far that if I remove the string id in the webmethod it is working fine and I am being able to reach the SetCurrentBaseVersion (not getting error 500)

**Working Code:**

CS

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetCurrentBaseVersion() //removed the string id
{
    // need to get here
}
```

JS

```
function postNewBaseLine(id) {
    var id = "300";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ManagerBaseKit.aspx/SetCurrentBaseVersion",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //data: {'id' :id},   removed the data
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success!');
        },
        statusCode: {
            500: function () {
                alert('got error 500');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass data as a json string you need to put the value of data in double quotes to make it string. The json format has key value pair within quotes. You need to understand **[Json Data Format](http://www.json.org/example.html)**

```
  data: "{'id': '" + id+ "'}",
```

This also worked without using quotes around key and value but [json document](http://www.json.org/example.html) which I referred states for putting quotes around key and value.

```
  data: "{id: " + id + "}",
```

For method having two parameters,

**Code behind**

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string CallMethodFromClient(string id, int amount)
{
```

**HTML**

```
    data: "{ id : " + id + ", amount : " + amount + " }"
```